# Пересечение и разность двух List<object>

Tags: c#

Есть списки сложных объектов. Нужно как-то их сравнить. Попытка применить `List.Distinct<>` и прочие методы почему-то проваливается.

Comment: Напишите конкретнее, что вы понимаете под "проваливается".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Разность списков находится методом [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
double[] numbers1 = { 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 };
double[] numbers2 = { 2.2 };

IEnumerable<double> onlyInFirstSet = numbers1.Except(numbers2);
```

Пересечение - методом [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int[] id1 = { 44, 26, 92, 30, 71, 38 };
int[] id2 = { 39, 59, 83, 47, 26, 4, 30 };

IEnumerable<int> both = id1.Intersect(id2);
```

Для того, чтобы эти методы работали над сложными объектами, необходимо, чтобы в классах этих объектов был переопределён оператор сравнения. Если переопределить оператор сравнения по каким-либо причинам невозможно, можно использовать версии методов [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb336390%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb355408%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), которым вторым параметром передаётся компаратор - объект класса, реализующего интерфейс [`IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx), в котором содержится логика сравнения объектов вашего класса.

Метод [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) не сработал, потому что он возвращает уникальные элементы одной коллекции, а не пересечение или разность двух коллекций. Для его корректной работы также требуется переопределённый оператор сравнения или компаратор.

Answer (score 5):

Начну с того, что `Distinct` - это метод не класса `List<>`, а метод статического класса `Enumerable` из пространства имен `System.Linq`. Этот метод расширяет интерфейс `IEnumerable<>`.

Конкретно для вашей задачи можно использовать методы `Intersect` и `Except`.

Из возможных проблем вижу две:

1. Ошибка новичка: потеряли `using System.Linq;` Без этой строки методы-расширения `IEnumerable<>` работать не будут.
2. Объект, который содержится в списке, некорректно реализует метод `Equals`. Тут выходом может быть написание реализации интерфейса `IEqualityComparer<>`.

Но зачем вы вообще используете списки? Посмотрите в сторону `HashSet<>` - там есть все методы для выполнения операций над множествами.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ сам. нужно для собственных объектов было сделать правильный дефолтный компаратор. после этого методы стали работать

Comment: Ваш ответ является урезанной версией другого ответа, написанного ранее и принятого, поэтому избыточен. Подобное сообщение можно оставить как комментарий.